# Unreal Engine : Two different Movement for an AI in two different NavMeshBounds

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I'm kinda new to Unreal Engine, and after following some tutorials, I tried to make an AI move in a specific area (in a random way) and if it sees a player, it immediatly runs into him. It works well, but now I want this AI to move randomly in a short area (navmeshbounds) and if it sees a player, it can run in a different area (navmeshbounds2) until it lose the player (or kill it idm) and go back to the first area. [image]

[image]

Here is the BluePrint I have made so far. I was thinking about using a cast, but I wonder if there is a real way.